# fork_call every 'n' seconds in AnyEvent

Tags: asynchronous, perl

I need to run fork workers every 5 seconds. Is there a way to do it more ideomatic? I'm embarrassed about $running variable.

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

use AnyEvent;
use AnyEvent::Util;

my $running;

sub work1 {
    say "work1";
    sleep 1;
}

sub work2 {
    say "work2";
    sleep 1;
}

sub do_work {

    my $worker_cv = AnyEvent->condvar;

    $worker_cv->begin;
    fork_call {
        work1();
    } sub {
        $worker_cv->end;
    };

    $worker_cv->begin;
    fork_call {
        work2();
    } sub {
        $worker_cv->end;
    };

    $worker_cv->cb(sub {
        $running = 0;
    });
}

my $timer = AnyEvent->timer(
    interval => 5,
    cb => sub {
        unless ($running) {
            $running = 1;
            do_work();
        }
    }
);

my $loop = AnyEvent->condvar;

$loop->recv;
```

Comment: You can make get/set `sub running{}` with 'static' `$running` if that would make you more comfortable. btw, where is `$running = 1;`?

Comment: Sorry, I've forgotten about `$running = 1`. Yes, static variable can be used, but it must be declared in do_work. Not very nice, because it is implicit for timer. I think there should be more AnyEvent-ish solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, here is a smaller scope for `$running` and `do_work()` doesn't need to bother with it,

```
sub do_work {

    my $worker_cv = AnyEvent->condvar;

    $worker_cv->begin;
    fork_call {
        work1();
    } sub {
        $worker_cv->end;
    };

    $worker_cv->begin;
    fork_call {
        work2();
    } sub {
        $worker_cv->end;
    };

    return $worker_cv;
}


my $running;
my $timer = AnyEvent->timer(
    interval => 5,
    cb => sub {      
        return if $running;

        $running = 1;
        do_work()->cb(sub{
            $running = 0;
        });
    }
);
```